# ASP.NET Response.Redirect shows CDATA to browser

Tags: asp.net, cdata

I recently moved a web application to a new server and every response.redirect ends up just showing the CDATA to the browser.  The form did post back, the changes were made, but the browser doesn't end up loading the new page, just shows the CDATA.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP redirect from asp.net is usually made using the HTTP header rather than any HTML output. Have you tried interogating the HTTP header to determine what is being returned?

Tools such as the following can help:
http://web-sniffer.net/

CDATA is an XML element, and as such I would not expect this as a sole output from the server. Could you try pasting the full output here for us to take a look at?

Comment: Yeah, that's what got me confused... For instance, this is the sole response:

<Data><Redirect><![CDATA[/unit/Advancement2.aspx?rankNo=1&scoutId=a9284339-8c36-4af0-88b2-47a98ce25f17]]></Redirect></Data>

It happens in ALL browsers as well...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's what got me confused... For instance, this is the sole response:  It happens in ALL browsers as well...